# Pyomo Using a non-set component as an indexed set

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, pyomo

I am new to Pyomo, but trying to formulate a model, which has one set of constraints, that I stuck to define. Lets assume, I have following simple code to show what I am trying to do

```
m = ConcreteModel()

m.rs = Set(initialize =[rs for rs in RS])
m.a = Set(initialize=[a for a in A])
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 10))

m.E = Var(m.rs, m.t)
m.tau = Var(m.a, m.t)
```

I know it is not correct to use a non-set component  `tau(t, a)` as an indexed component, this is just to show simply I need:

```
 m.E[rs, t] == sum(m.E[rs, t + tau(t, a)] for all a in ...)
```

The value of  `tau(t, a)` are calculated within the model when solving it.  Any idea, how this sort of constraint con be written?
Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Indexing by a variable is not really available in mathematical programming tools. It is in many Constraint Programming systems. In Math Programming, we usually handle this by introducing binary variables. The precise formulation depends on the details.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen! How can I discuss the details with you?

Comment: How large is the range of values that `tau(t,a)` can take? If it's not too large, you can replace it with a set of binary variables `tau(t,a,i)` where `i` represents the value. Then you can make your constraint `m.E[rs, t] == sum(m.E[rs, t + i] * tau(t,a,i))`

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: I learnt that Pyomo handles Differential and Algebraic Equations. Do you know how this condition can be written in DAE form? I already transformed my model to DAE format, but still have issue with transforming this relation. Thanks!